# Bounding box onscreen correct, but shifted up when I use the same rect to get a Texture2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a small script that takes screenshots of a cube with a 2d boundingbox drawn around it and then of the same cube, but just the contents of the bounding box.

I do this first by a standard call to Screen

```
ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(filename)
```

then I call `SnapShotInBoundingBox()` in my code to create a Texture2d from the rect of the bounding box and save that as a screenshot.

The problem I have is the texture when saved seems to shift the image up a few pixels.

```
public void OnGUI()  //draws the boundingbox 
{

   Bounds b = theCube.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds;
   Camera cam = Camera.main;
    if (cam == null) return;
   //The object is behind us
   if (cam.WorldToScreenPoint(b.center).z < 0) return;

   //All 8 vertices of the bounds
   pts[0] = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(new Vector3(b.center.x + b.extents.x, b.center.y + b.extents.y, b.center.z + b.extents.z));
   pts[1] = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(new Vector3(b.center.x + b.extents.x, b.center.y + b.extents.y, b.center.z - b.extents.z));
   pts[2] = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(new Vector3(b.center.x + b.extents.x, b.center.y - b.extents.y, b.center.z + b.extents.z));
   pts[3] = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(new Vector3(b.center.x + b.extents.x, b.center.y - b.extents.y, b.center.z - b.extents.z));
   pts[4] = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(new Vector3(b.center.x - b.extents.x, b.center.y + b.extents.y, b.center.z + b.extents.z));
   pts[5] = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(new Vector3(b.center.x - b.extents.x, b.center.y + b.extents.y, b.center.z - b.extents.z));
   pts[6] = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(new Vector3(b.center.x - b.extents.x, b.center.y - b.extents.y, b.center.z + b.extents.z));
   pts[7] = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(new Vector3(b.center.x - b.extents.x, b.center.y - b.extents.y, b.center.z - b.extents.z));

   //Get them in GUI space
   for (int i = 0; i < pts.Length; i++) pts[i].y = Screen.height - pts[i].y;

   //Calculate the min and max positions
   Vector3 min = pts[0];
   Vector3 max = pts[0];
   for (int i = 1; i < pts.Length; i++)
   {
       min = Vector3.Min(min, pts[i]);
       max = Vector3.Max(max, pts[i]);
   }

   //Construct a rect of the min and max positions and apply some margin
   r = Rect.MinMaxRect(min.x, min.y, max.x, max.y);
   r.xMin -= BoundingBoxMargin;
   r.xMax += BoundingBoxMargin;
   r.yMin -= BoundingBoxMargin;
   r.yMax += BoundingBoxMargin;

    //Render the bounding box
    GUI.backgroundColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);

    GUI.DrawTexture(r, boundingBoxTexture);
}

byte[] SnapShotInBoundingBox()
{

    Rect lasso = new Rect(r.x, r.y, r.width+3, r.height);
    Debug.Log(lasso);
    tex = new Texture2D((int)lasso.width, (int)lasso.height, TextureFormat.RGBA32,false);
    tex.ReadPixels(lasso, 0, 0);        //only render what's inside the bounding box,including the box itself
    tex.Apply();

    return tex.EncodeToJPG();

}
```

Comment: Could you add both pictures for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why the two snapshots result in different images is that

> The [CaptureScreenshot](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot.html) returns immediately on Android. The screen capture continues in the background. The resulting screen shot is saved in the file system after a few seconds.

Meanwhile the camera might move so that `SnapShotInBoundingBox();` returns a slightly different picture.

---

You should probably call the methods in the opposite order:

```
SnapShotInBoundingBox();
ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(filename);
```

Comment: Thanks, no the camera is fixed in position for both shots, also checked the rect coords of the bounding box and they remain the same throughout.